# How to find out PLSQL Compilation errors

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
create or replace procedure address_insert 
as

CREATE type colorarray is varray(10) of varchar2(10);
CREATE type cities is varray(6) of varchar2(20);
CREATE type states is varray(6) of varchar2(15);
CREATE type zipcodes is varray(6) of number(10);
CREATE type countries is varray(6) of varchar2(15);

city cities;
Colour colorarray;
zip zipcodes;
state states;
country countries;
id1 number;
x number;
ca number;
r number;

begin
x:=1;
ca:=1;
id1:=1;
r:=1;
city:=cities('Visakhapatnam','Hyderabad','Bangalore','Chennai','Kurnool','secunderabad');
colour :=colorarray('Red', 'Blue', 'green', 'Dark blue', 'yellow', 'orange', 'brown', 'black', 'white', 'purple');
state:=states('Telangana','Tamilnadu','Karnataka','Andhra Pradesh','Madya Pradesh','Kerala');
zip:=zipcodes(530081,500072,316190,981272,717999,621896);
country:=countries('India','Nepal','Pakistan','USA','Bangladesh','UK');

while x<(select count(persons_id) from person_data) loop

if ca>10 then
ca:=1;
end if;
if r>6 then
r:=1;
end if;

insert into persons_addresses(Address_id,Persons_id,flatname,flatno,house_color,contact_person,address_line1,address_line2,address_line3,
city,district,state,zipcode,country) values
(id1,(select persons_id from (select persons_id,row_number()over (order by persons_id) as rn from person_data)tmp where rn=x),
(SELECT dbms_random.string('L', 15) from dual),(SELECT round(dbms_random.value(100,1000)) num FROM dual),colour(ca),
(SELECT dbms_random.string('L', 5)|| ' ' ||dbms_random.string('L', 7) from dual),
(SELECT dbms_random.string('L', 9)|| ' ' ||dbms_random.string('L', 6)|| ' ' ||dbms_random.string('L', 8)|| ' ' ||dbms_random.string('L', 10) 
FROM dual),(SELECT dbms_random.string('L', 9)|| ' ' ||dbms_random.string('L', 6)|| ' ' ||
dbms_random.string('L', 8)|| ' ' ||dbms_random.string('L', 10) FROM dual),(SELECT dbms_random.string('L', 9)|| ' ' ||
dbms_random.string('L', 6)|| ' ' ||dbms_random.string('L', 8)|| ' ' ||dbms_random.string('L', 10) FROM dual),city(r),(SELECT dbms_random.string('L', 9) from dual),
state(r),zip(r),country(r));
commit;
id1:=id1+1;
ca:=ca+1;
r:=r+1;
x:=x+1;
end loop;
EXCEPTION  -- exception handlers begin
  WHEN OTHERS THEN  -- handles all other errors
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (SQLCODE|| ' ' || SQLERRM);
end;
```

There is a compilation warning.

> Warning: execution completed with warning procedure address_insert
>   Compiled.

when executed:

```
execute address_insert
```

> Error starting at line 1 in command: execute address_insert Error
>   report: ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PLS-00905: object
>   DATAFOCUS_GROUP.ADDRESS_INSERT is invalid ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
>   PL/SQL: Statement ignored
>   06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
>   *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
>   *Action:

Is there any way we can find out the compilation errors?

```
SELECT *
  FROM USER_ERRORS
  WHERE NAME = 'ADDRESS_INSERT'
```

The above query helped retrieve the errors.

Errors:

> "PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CREATE" when expecting one of the
>   following:
>
> begin function pragma procedure subtype type      current cursor delete    exists
>   prior external language The symbol "CREATE" was ignored. "
>   the above error have been encountered due to varray definition.
>   Is there any alternative?

other errors:

> "PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SELECT" when expecting one of the
>   following:
>
> ( - + case mod new not null          continue avg count current
>   exists max min prior sql stddev    sum variance execute forall merge
>   time timestamp interval    date       pipe
>
> , from "

Answer (score 6):

You can get compilation errors from the DBA_ERRORS or USER_ERRORS views. In your case, try something like

```
SELECT *
  FROM USER_ERRORS
  WHERE NAME = 'ADDRESS_INSERT'
```

Remember that in Oracle table, view, procedure, package, etc names are `UPPER_CASE` by default, even if they're shown in `lower_case` in your source code.

Right off the top I can see that `CREATE TYPE` is not valid in a procedure. You probably want something like

```
TYPE COLORARRAY IS VARRAY(10) OF VARCHAR2(10)
```

See [the PL/SQL Reference Manual section on defining collection types.](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/composites.htm#LNPLS005) for further information.

Best of luck.

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right. I got it now. Thanks Bob!

Answer (score 4):

If you're in SQL*Plus, do a 'SHOW ERRORS'. This also works in SQL Developer's SQL Worksheet.

[image]

If you're in a proper IDE - you'll see the errors at compile time.

[image]

Comment: How is 'show errors' going to work? Is it going to print (for eg. procedure)names and their errors. Do we execute it alone ?or we associate it with plsql blck?.

Comment: @EmilySharon `show errors` in SQL Developer works same way it does  in  SQL*PLUS. Just type it after your `create procedure|function|type|package|etc` statement as shown in pic#1