# Error while trying to create a package for authentication in oracle apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I wanted to implement custom authentication in my oracle apex application. So for that I wrote some pl/sql codes to create a package.

```
create or replace package body user_tools_pak
as
  function login_auth(field_userid in varchar2,field_password in varchar2) 
  return boolean is
  begin
    select user_id
    from   USER_TABLE
    where  user_id = field_userid
    and    password = field_password;
    apex_util.set_session_state(p_name  => 'SESSION_USERID', p_value => user_id);
    return true;
  exception
    when no_data_found then
      return false;
  end login_auth;
end user_tools_pak;
```

But when I run it an error occurs.

[image]

Is there anything wrong with my code or am I missing something?

Comment: check your variable names, filed_user_id  for example. and in general, there are ways to identify what was the actual compilation issue, described, for example,  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40421202/how-to-find-out-plsql-compilation-errors)

Comment: Passwords should be hashed, not stored as plain text.

Answer (score 2):

The function should accept p_username and p_password as parameters and return boolean. This can be found in the help section of the authentication function name

> Specify the name of the function that will verify the user's username
>   and password, after they were entered on a login page. If you enter
>   nothing, you allow any username/password to succeed. The function
>   itself can be defined in the authentication's 'PL/SQL Code' textarea,
>   within a package or as a stored function.
>
> This function must return a boolean to the login procedure that calls
>   it. It has 2 input parameters 'p_username' and 'p_password' that can
>   be used to access the values an end user entered on the login page.

Examples
Enter the following code in the 'PL/SQL Code' textarea

```
function my_authentication (
    p_username in varchar2,
    p_password in varchar2 )
    return boolean
is
    l_user my_users.user_name%type := upper(p_username);
    l_id   my_users.id%type;
    l_hash my_users.password_hash%type;
begin
    begin
        select id  , password_hash
          into l_id, l_hash
          from my_users
         where user_name = l_user;
    exception when no_data_found then
        l_hash := '-invalid-';
    end;

return l_hash = rawtohex(sys.dbms_crypto.hash (
                    sys.utl_raw.cast_to_raw (
                        p_password||l_id||l_user ),
                    sys.dbms_crypto.hash_sh512 ));
end;
```

and my_authentication as 'Authentication Function'.

[image: screenshot]